# Laravel slow mysql query latency

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

```
echo "\nexec first time:";
$currentTime = microtime(true);
$users->paginate($request->length, ['*'], 'page', $request->start/$request->length + 1);
echo microtime(true) - $currentTime;

echo "\nexec second time:";
$currentTime = microtime(true);
$users->paginate($request->length, ['*'], 'page', $request->start/$request->length + 1);
echo microtime(true) - $currentTime;
```

The above is the code in my controller for testing the latency when query the mysql. As you can see I execute the same command twice. The execute latency is different.

```
exec first time: 2.7011959552765
exec second time: 0.78873896598816
```

The above is the output of the performance. During the Laravel document, the server provider contains the DI pattern to share the DB connection. If we are not recreate the connection then what happened is this result?
If the result is belongs to recreation, then how can I share the connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

On a "cold" server, everything is on disk.  A query must pull things into RAM to be performed.  This typically means that the first time you run a query it takes X seconds; the second time it takes more like X/10 seconds.

Another issue is with "pagination", especially if it is done via `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.  All of the "offset" rows much be stepped over.  So, as the user 'pages' through the data, the pages will come up slower and slower -- because of stepping over more and more rows.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination